# Current folder name in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there a simple way to get the name of the current folder name or do I have to do it with regexp?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
dirname = File.basename(Dir.getwd)
```

`File.basename()` returns the base name even when its argument is the path of a directory.

The following code prints *kiamlaluno* for me, where */home/kiamlaluno* is the home directory in my Ubuntu installation.

```
puts File.basename('/home/kiamlaluno')
```

The same does `puts File.basename(Dir.getwd)`, when the current directory is /home/kiamlaluno.

Answer (score 7):

```
irb(main):001:0> Dir.getwd
=> "C:/Documents and Settings/UserName"
```

or did I misunderstand your question ?

Update: Try one of the below

```
File.split(Dir.getwd)[-1]
Pathname.new(Dir.getwd).basename.to_s
```

Comment: Yeah I want to have only the current folder name, not folder path. In this case: UserName. Is there a way to do this in Ruby or do you have to use regexp?

Comment: File.basename(Dir.getwd) will return only last folder name.